# Extract text and write to a new file in Perl

Tags: string, perl, file, text, extract

Simply put, I want to extract text from a file and save that text to a new file, using Perl.

Here is my code, thus far:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Slurp;
use FileHandle;

use Fcntl qw(:DEFAULT :flock :seek); # Import LOCK_* constants

my $F_IN = FileHandle->new("<$ARGV[0]");
my $F_OUT = FileHandle->new(">PerlTest.txt");

while (my $line = $F_IN->getline) {
    $line =~ m|foobar|g;
    $F_OUT->print($line);
    # I want to only copy the text that matches, not the whole line.
    # I changed the example text to 'foobar' to avoid confusion.
}

$F_IN->close();
$F_OUT->close();
```

Obviously, it's copying the line. How can I extract and print specific text from a file, instead of the whole line?

Comment: m//g in void context makes no sense. And what specific text do you want copied? "thebigredpillow"?

Comment: Well, it's just an example.  I could've made it foobar, I suppose.  What I would like is search the file for a string, using regular expressions. If it finds it, copy said string to a file.  Why does m//g make no sense?  I've used it before for other jobs, just not searching and extracting text to a new file.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you think m//g does in void context? I can't even imagine a sensical meaning for it.

Comment: Well I've used it before, similar to above, for a substitute regular expression, searching and replacing through a whole file (not line-by-line).  But I digress.  Whatever way which arrives at the solution to the question above would be great. Thank you.

Comment: That something different did something useful has nothing to do with that being discussed. I didn't say "g" is useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use capturing parentheses to grab the matched string:

```
while (my $line = $F_IN->getline) {
    if ($line =~ m|(thebigredpillow)|) {
        $F_OUT->print("$1\n");
    }
}
```

See [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Answer (score 3):

If it can only happen once per line:

```
while (<>) {
   print "$1\n" if /(thebigredpillow)/;
}
```

If it can happen multiple times per line:

```
while (<>) {
   while (/(thebigredpillow)/g) {
      print "$1\n";
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
script file.in >file.out
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use IO::All;

my @lines = io($ARGV[0])->slurp;

foreach(@lines) {
    if(/thebigredpillow/g) {
        $_ >> io('PerlTest.txt');
    }
}
```